# Stop openssh from changing window title

Tags: powershell

I generally have several powershell windows open, with SSH sessions into different remote hosts.

It can become a pain easily finding the window I want, so attempted to set the powershell window title to the remote host name.  The only issue is that as soon as I start the ssh process, the window title changes to "OpenSSH SSH client", which defeats the purpose.

Is there any advice on how I can keep the host name?

If not, any other advice on a simple way to distinguish powershell windows from one another?

Comment: Anytime you spin off to a new shell, that shells properties are controlled by that shell. Just like you'd have to do with putty session, like in the Q&A --- https://serverfault.com/questions/178469/set-puttys-window-title-to-name-of-loaded-session

Comment: @postanote, I've looked at the linked article, but it all seems like it's putty GUI or config specific, so haven't been able to make the leap of logic you're alluding too.  Can you offer some more information?

Comment: Putty was just an example - It is just another SSH client, so these things all act like a window in x mode. So, messing with the title using the putty GUI is as my previous pointer, but you can do similar at the command SSH command line. Another putty example here, but command line --- http://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/how-to-set-the-putty-window-title-via-script --- and here which is covering just Linux SSH session examples --- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40830/fix-terminal-title-after-ssh-remote-logging-to-another-machine

Comment: No worries. I guess I should have posted these as answers, so that if they work for you, thus you could mark them as the accepted answer for other to benefit from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Windows Terminal.

When you have installed it you can see [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-set-up-a-tab-profile-in-windows-terminal-to-automatically-ssh-into-a-linux-box) how to setup a ssh client.

Add the following line to the settings of the host:
'suppressApplicationTitle: true,'

You can make an entry for all your hosts.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

As per @postanote's comment in my question, the remote host needs to set the client's terminal title.

From http://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/how-to-set-the-putty-window-title-via-script

ssh into the remote host, then execute from within the ssh session:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;testing\007"
```